# HTML/CSS: Table with sticky header to span always over the heigth of the viewport

Tags: html, css

Concerning all the Posts i have found on the topic the problem seems as old as the wxistence of HTML tables....

I have a few pages with tables in my Web-Application that i wanted to have with sticky headlines and then scrollable INSIDE the page.

That was not so a big problem, but now i wonder, if there is a way to get around the "style="heigth...." property and make them sticky with having the table always reaching the full heigth of viewport....

Thyts my JSCode

```html
<style>
    {#Sticky Table Headers#}
    table td,
    table th {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    thead {
      top: 0;
      position: sticky;
    }
    .table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
      background-color: #63a1ff;
    }

</style>
```

and thats my html start div for the table that fixes the height-range

`<div class="table-responsive" style="position: relative; height: 600px">`

so now the Question again: Is there a way to set the table to use the given viewport height beneath the sticky headline for scrolling?

I tried all possible combinations of bootstrap 5 tags but nothing seemed to work....